# How to sum the values in for loop

Tags: javascript, protractor

```
element.all(by.tagName('strong')).count().then(function (number) {
    for (let i = 2; i < number; i=i+3) {
        element.all(by.tagName('strong')).get(i).getText().then(function (text2) {
                var text3 = text2.split(" ");
               var price = text3[1];
                console.log(price);
        });

    }

});
```

Output:
65000
50000
100000
85000

Here i wanted to get the sum of all the values.
Can anyone please help me in getting the sum of all the values.

Comment: look into async/await. Not related to your problem directly. But you won't have ANY problems if you eliminate the use of `.then()` in your code

Comment: you should read protractor documentation first https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.reduce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep track of a `total` variable, that you add to for each element's text you want to compare.

You need to convert the text of the element into a number. `parseFloat()` is one way to do that.

When working with async code (Promises, .then(), etc), you can only use values by chaining another `.then()` to the promise chain, to make sure the value is available. If you try to log `total` outside of a `.then()`, that console.log will execute long before your text totalling code runs.

Summing up, here's an example, that also removes the need for an extra element grab, since it looks like you can use `.getText()` on a collection:

```js
let total = 0;
element.all(by.tagName('strong')).getText().then(function(strongTags) {
  for (let i = 2; i < strongTags.length; i = i + 3) {
    total += parseFloat(strongTags[i].split(' ')[1]);
  }
  return total;
}).then(function(total) => {
  console.log('The total is', total);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this using `.reduce`

```
let sum = element.all(by.tagName('strong')).reduce(function(acc, elem) {
  return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
    var text3 = text2.split(" ");
    var price = text3[1];
    return acc + price;
  });
}, 0);
```

UPD:

`.reduce` callback also accepts index if you want to skip particular elements.

```
let sum = element.all(by.tagName('strong')).reduce(function(acc, elem, index) {
  if ((index - 2) % 3 == 0) {
    return acc + 0;
  }
  return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
    var text3 = text2.split(" ");
    var price = text3[1];
    return acc + price;
  });
}, 0);
```

Comment: This doesn't handle the async nature nor the skipping of elements